# Alias to Show Tables MySQL Result

Tags: mysql, sql, list

When executing SHOW TABLES FROM *your_db_name_here* inside MySQL, the result has *Tables_in_{your_db_name_here}* as its indexes. I'd like to change that, like this:

```
SHOW TABLES as _tables FROM mydb;
```

or something like

```
SELECT Tables_in_mydb AS _tables FROM (SHOW TABLES FROM mydb);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's usually easier to interact with the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` database:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tables-table.html

Example:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME AS _tables 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'mydb'
```

Comment: I was hoping that this wouldn't be the only solution since I would have to establish a different database connection to work with that. But I guess I don't have much of a choice.

Comment: Why do you need a separate connection? Something like this should work: `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='mydb'`

Comment: Interestingly it did, I thought since it was a different database it would need a different connection link. Thanks